# Extjs5 - idProperty dosen't take effect

Tags: javascript, extjs, web

I have defined a custom Ext.Model, which is called `itrip.model.City`, And the primary key of this model is `cityId`, so I changed the default `idProperty` from `'id'` to `'cityId'`, but it turns out a little bit weird, when I call `Ext.model.load()` to request my server, the actual request URL turns out to be

http://localhost:8080/admin/city?_dc=1422349415598&id=itrip.model.City-1

See the param is still 'id' and the value is 'itrip.model.City-1', I don't know how is this come about.

Hope anyone could help :-)

Here's my code:

```
Ext.define('itrip.model.City', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'city',
        idProperty: 'cityId',
    fields: [
        {name: 'cityId', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'countryId', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'cityNameZh', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'cityNameEn', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'cityCode', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'show', type: 'int'}
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'city',
    }
});

var city = itrip.model.City.load(1, {
    success: function(city1) {
      //omit...  
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug. I have had same problem on ExtJS 5.0.1. Upgrade on ExtJS 5.1.0.